# Он предпочел первое второму, так как неизвестно(,) что будет с последним через несколько лет, - запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Он предпочел первое второму, так как неизвестно(,) что будет с последним через несколько лет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая.

Comment: Вы ещё не проверяете написанное? Тогда начтите.

Comment: А какой контекст? "Последнее" относится к упомянутому второму блюду или к десерту? Или второе милостиво оставили "последнему", который отправляется куда-то надолго?

Answer (score 1):

Если дело только в запятой, то она необходима, так как отделяет придаточное предложение от главного.